# Having trouble getting range with onEdit function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Whenever a cell is edited, I want it to get the value of cell "H1". I have tried this:

```js
   function onEdit(e){ 
      var range = e.range;
       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range).setValue("H1");
}
```

However it is not working. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Doesn't `setValue` set the value, not get it? Also, the function doesn't return anything

Comment: @evolutionxbox trigger functions are not meant to return anything :) They are just triggered upon events.

Comment: @Marios good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) to range "H1" first, then use [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) to write it on the edited cell:

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var range = e.range;
  var newValue = range.getSheet().getRange("H1").getValue();
  range.setValue(newValue);
}
```